# 7-Zip batch script no longer compressing files in Windows 10

Tags: batch-file, 7zip

I have a .BAT file that was as follows:

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zG.exe" a -mx9 cvseagle.7z ^
cvseagle.def ^
cvseagle.snd ^
cvseagle.sff ^
cvseagle.air ^
cvseagle.cns ^
buffering.vns ^
cvseagle.cds ^
config.txt ^
cvssystem.lol ^
point.lol ^
movelist* ^
読んで下さい.txt ^
"READ OR DIE".txt
pause
```

However, now it no longer works, most likely because I just updated Windows 10 (does not read the command correctly anymore) and I changed it to this... and it still doesn't want to work:

```
@echo off
start /D    "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\" 7zG.exe -mx9 a  cvseagle.7z ^
cvseagle.def ^
cvseagle.snd ^
cvseagle.sff ^
cvseagle.air ^
cvseagle.cns ^
buffering.vns ^
cvseagle.cds ^
config.txt ^
cvssystem.lol ^
point.lol ^
movelist* ^
読んで下さい.txt ^
"READ OR DIE".txt
pause
```

When I try to do it now, it says "Access is denied. Cannot open file cvseagle.7z"

So what gives? Why does my script, which has worked FINE for SEVERAL Windows versions for YEARS, suddenly not want to work?

This doesn't work either:

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zG.exe" -mx9 a  cvseagle.7z ^
cvseagle.def ^
cvseagle.snd ^
cvseagle.sff ^
cvseagle.air ^
cvseagle.cns ^
buffering.vns ^
cvseagle.cds ^
config.txt ^
cvssystem.lol ^
point.lol ^
movelist* ^
読んで下さい.txt ^
"READ OR DIE".txt
pause
```

The directory is `X:\WinMUGEN\chars\cvseagle`. I am on Windows 10 20H2 OS Build 19042.867 with Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.551.0

Comment: Is there another process holding onto cvseagle.7z?

Comment: It could also be related to what directory the script is running in. Running the script in `C:\` or some other folder that requires Administrator access would give you that error.

Comment: In your lower code example, `"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\" 7zG.exe` is not correct, it should be `C:\"Program Files"\7-Zip\7zG.exe`, and more correctly `"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zG.exe"`, as in your upper code example. Also are you sure that your codepage on the new system supports the Japanese characters? What happens if you use `"%SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com"`, and set it to `932`?

Comment: @Compo Yes, I’m sure it works; it was working fine a month ago. Also, I made a mistake when I posted the question in what my new script actually looks like, please reread.

Comment: @jwdonahue No, there isn’t

Comment: Yo've introduced another issue. You've now included a smart _(curly)_ quote, instead of a dumb, _(straight)_, quote. i.e. `“C:\Program Files\7-Zip\"` should be `"C:\Program Files\7-Zip"`

Comment: …a bracket `[` or `]`! If you don't show us, what your actual command is, we cannot know for sure what its issue may be.

Comment: When you use the `/D` option, it changes the working directory. Are you sure that `cvseagle.7z`, `cvseagle.def`, `cvseagle.snd`, `cvseagle.sff`, `cvseagle.air`, `cvseagle.cns`, `buffering.vns`, `cvseagle.cds`, `config.txt`, `cvssystem.lol`, `point.lol`, `movelist*`, `読んで下さい.txt`, and `"READ OR DIE".txt` are all in `%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip`

Comment: @Compo I see. That’s the problem then; I’m trying to get it to run on files in the current directory from when I double-click the .BAT file (the .BAT file resides in the same location as those files, which is not the 7z directory) How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Use `"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zG.exe" a -mx9 …` like you did in the first example. If you need to continue with other commands whilst the compression is running, and therefore need the `start` command, then use `Start "" "%ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7zG.exe" a -mx9 …`

Comment: @Compo But when I do that, it does absolutely nothing at all. It does not touch the 7z. It's as if it NEVER ran the program, and I don't think it is.

Comment: Just to clarify, there was a typo, _(missing `%`)_, in my last comment. You haven't replicated it without noticing, have you? `"%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7zG.exe" a -mx9 …`

Comment: @Compo Still does absolutely nothing

Comment: Probably you had ran batch from UNC-path. Default current folder was **%windir%**. This folder has read-only right for Users-group. So process **7zG.exe** didn't have right to access new-created archive file - it didn't exist.

Comment: Why are you using 7zg.exe instead of 7z.exe?

Comment: You must have write permission for a directory named `X:\WinMUGEN\chars\cvseagle` in order to create your archive `cvseagle.7z` there.You should also have sufficient space in that location for the new archive. It is also essential that, at the time you run the file, if `X:` is a mapped network location, that it is connected and available. Those things are completely outside of the scope of your question, and are therefore not covered in my answer, which has been tested to work on the same OS version, with the same file names.

Comment: @Compo It’s an internal drive, and yes, I have write permission. Otherwise I couldn’t create or move files there at all.

Comment: My code works, you have an issue outside of that code, which you've so far been unable to communicate to us. Please copy the batch file and files to be archived onto your Desktop, and try it there!

Comment: I should also mention that the batch files are opening in Windows Terminal. Is behavior of batch files any different?

Comment: @Compo Still does nothing when copied to the desktop. No file updates, even though there are newer files in the directory than there are in the archive.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue may be related to the doublequoted filename, `"READ OR DIE".txt`, which should technically be `"READ OR DIE.txt"`.

When you split your command over several lines, any which begin with a doublequote, must be preceded with a space character.

If `7zG.exe` is genuinely appropriate for your task, then I'd offer the following modification of your provided command:

```sh
"%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7zG.exe" -mx9 a cvseagle.7z ^
cvseagle.def ^
cvseagle.snd ^
cvseagle.sff ^
cvseagle.air ^
cvseagle.cns ^
buffering.vns ^
cvseagle.cds ^
config.txt ^
cvssystem.lol ^
point.lol ^
movelist* ^
読んで下さい.txt ^
 "READ OR DIE.txt"
Pause
```

Comment: BTW, I would for best practice, doublequote every filename, _(including `cvseagle.7z`)_, and therefore precede each split line with a space, as my standard syntax.

Comment: It still doesn't do anything

Comment: It works using `7z.exe`, I've no idea about `7zG.exe`, because I assumed that was a GUI version, and this is batch, i.e the CLI. I've tried the exact code above, _(except for that change)_, only this afternoon, using version 16.4 of `7z.exe`, I found inside a clients `PeaZip` directory on a Windows 10 PC. I even created the exact filenames you had, including the Japanese named one. Please do not test my code with any other filenames.

Comment: I’m not; I copypasted that exactly as you had it.

Comment: Try it with `7z.exe`, as I did.

Comment: Interestingly enough, it does run the program, but it doesn't recognize the files

7-Zip 19.00 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2018 Igor Pavlov : 2019-02-21

Open archive: cvseagle.7z
--
Path = cvseagle.7z
Type = 7z
Physical Size = 32
Headers Size = 0
Solid = -
Blocks = 0

Scanning the drive:
0 files, 0 bytes

Updating archive: cvseagle.7z

Add new data to archive: 0 files, 0 bytes


Files read from disk: 0
Archive size: 32 bytes (1 KiB)
Everything is Ok
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Where are your batch file and the other files located? **Please do not answer in the comments, put all of the pertinent information into your question, for everyone to read.**